# error when trying to insert data to sqlite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to run an sql function that inserts data into a table. I am following the example explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm) but whenever i run the script no data is inserted into the table and neither does the script return the message. Here is the code: What can i be possibly be doing wrong?

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, request
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm
from .forms import RegistrationForm
import sqlite3 as sql

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')


@app.route('/registration', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def registration():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
      try:
         card_id = request.form['card_id']
         pin = request.form['pin']
         account_id = request.form['account_id']


         with sql.connect("testDB.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO atm_card (card_id,pin,account_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(card_id,pin,account_id) )

            con.commit()
            msg = "Record successfully added"
      except:
         con.rollback()
         msg = "error in insert operation"

      finally:
         return render_template("index.html", msg=msg)
         con.close()

    else:
       return render_template("registration.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see, possibly a typo or something else, is that you have *four* placeholders in the `VALUES` clause of your `INSERT`, but you seem to only intend to specify *three* columns.  Change this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO atm_card (card_id,pin,account_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(card_id,pin,account_id) )
```

to this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO atm_card (card_id,pin,account_id) VALUES (?,?,?)",(card_id,pin,account_id) )
```